# iOS wont delete my App Data after uninstall of MAUI Application

Tags: ios, maui

I am using MAUI.Essentials to store data in secure storage.

```
SecureStorage.SetAsync(key, securedValue);
```

But uninstalling the Application in android is deleting app data but the same is not working in iOS.
According to [this](https://salon.helpsite.com/articles/43396-ios-wont-delete-my-app-data-when-i-uninstallreinstall-the-same-data-is-always-there) post we need to turn off the backup in iCloud.
I am currently testing in iPhone simulator and under settings I have not logged in to iCloud.

Also I tried below code to manually delete the app data

```
if (VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver)
            {
                services.AppCache.Clear();
            }
```

But I don't want to delete it manually.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Secure storage maps to the keychain on iOS. Keychain data is not removed when the app is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Given that (by iOS design) there isn't any way to delete data from iOS secure storage when app is deleted, you'll want a way to detect that there is "obsolete" data there, if the app gets deleted then re-installed.

When you detect this, you can decide whether to ignore or delete that "obsolete" data, so that it isn't visible to the new installation. Thus, it is as if it was not kept (other than the slight waste of storage -- never put anything large into secure storage).

I do this by creating an empty file in app local (not secure) storage, at the same time as saving the data to secure storage.

When app starts up, I check if that empty file exists. If it is not there, then I know anything in secure storage is "obsolete", left over from a previous install of app, so I erase it (if I don't want it to be visible when re-install).

Note that this also handles the case where user goes to Settings, finds the app, and does "Delete Data". Even if they don't uninstall app, the next time it runs, it will act as if it is a new install.

Answer (score 0):

In the Maui official document ([Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios#platform-differences)) wrote:

> KeyChain is used to store values securely on iOS devices. The
> SecRecord used to store the value has a Service value set to
> [YOUR-APP-BUNDLE-ID].microsoft.maui.essentials.preferences.
>
> In some cases, KeyChain data is synchronized with iCloud, and
> uninstalling the application may not remove the secure values from
> user devices.

You can try to turn off iCloud with a real device, iCloud cannot be used in the simulator. You also can let the app start to call the delete code in your question to determine whether it is the first installation to delete the data in the KeyChain.